# How to show a single vector which represnting three linearly indepenent vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have three vectors, which are linearly independent A, B, C:

A=<`a1,b1,c1`>

B=<`a2,b2,c2`>

C=<`a3,b3,c3`>

I want to show single vector Let's say: 'D' represting above three linarly independent vector. Will it be simply adding like:

D=A+B+C;

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you mean that you want to show that $D$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $A, B, $ and $C$ ($D=aA+bB+cC$)?  By the way, the way you wrote it, $B=C$.

Comment: Sorry, It was typing mistake.Yes, I want to show a single Vector represting A, B and C. I checked that these vectors are linearly independent in my case.

Comment: I do not follow what you want to do.  "I want to show single vector representing above three linearly independent vectors."  It is not clear what you mean here by "representing."  What property do you want $D$ to have?  How should $D$ relate to $A,B,C$?  Are you expecting this to somehow be unique in some way?

Comment: If you have three linearly independent vectors $A,B,C$ then *any* linear combination of these, for example $A+B+C$ or more generally $\alpha A + \beta B + \gamma C$ for scalars $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, will be within the span of $A,B,C$ and as such linearly dependent to the set $\{A,B,C\}$.  Such a linear combination would not in my opinion "represent" the three vectors however.

Comment: Vector D should represent all three vectors (A,B,C). If these vectors (A,B,C) are linearly independent, we can consider them as points in space R. And then by just adding them (A+B+C) will give us a new point (D), from origin It will be a vector. sorry if it's misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is $$\vec{d}=\alpha\vec{a}+\beta\vec{b}+\gamma\vec{c}$$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are real numbers.You will get a system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it by using an augmented matrix equation.

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  a_{1}&a_{2}&a_{3}&d_{1}\\
  b_{1}&b_{2}&b_{3}&d_{2}\\
  c_{1}&c_{2}&c_{3}&d_{3}
\end{array}
\right] 
$$

which will result in the constants necessary to express $\lvert d\rvert$ when on reduced row echelon form which is achieved by using row operations on the augmented matrix. If the answer to the reduced row echelon form is stated as $k_{1}, k_{2}, k_{3}$ then $\lvert d\rvert = k_{1}\lvert A \rvert + k_{2}\lvert B \rvert + k_{3} \lvert C \rvert$

Comment: This is a fine answer to a question that might be not at all related to what the OP asked above.  What makes you think that the OP asked how to represent $D$ as a linear combination of $A,B,C$?

Comment: From the wording in the question it seemed like OP was interested in representing a given vector $\lvert d \rvert$ as a linear combination of three vectors that are linearly independent. Do you interpret the wording in the question in another way?

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you might want, (and this is a guess!), is to put the three vectors into a matrix:

$$M= \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{A} | \mathbf{B}| \mathbf{C}\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} a_1&a_2&a_3\\b_1&b_2&b_3\\c_1&c_2&c_3\end{pmatrix} .$$

An alternative "representation" would be the transpose $M^T$.

By the way, the answer would be the same if the vectors were not linearly independent.  So what doe linear independence have to do with your question?

Comment: I want a single vector to represent them.  Can I consider them (A, B, C) points in Space and simply add them to find resultant, resultant point from origin will be a vector (D)?

Comment: I think you are looking for Dr. Graubner's solution, which is what you are saying but more general.  Three linearly independent vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$, so you can get any vector from a linear combination of them.